# Heroku deployment - 2 github projects

Tags: python, angular, heroku, flask

I have two projects(repos) in git hub:

1. Frontend - Angular
2. Backend - Python (Flask)

I want to deploy my app(server+client) to heroku cloud.

in all the guides I saw how to deploy only one project. 
in project has his own setup file (project.json, requirements.txt).

what is the best way to deply this App at heroku?

Thanks!

Comment: are you deploying in common run-time or private space ?

Comment: Both repos are public and deployment on heroku in my free account

Comment: if thats the case I would assume you are not in the Heroku private space were you could have internally communicated between front and back end, by deploying 2 apps. For now if works deploy two apps one for client and one for the server and use the generated Heroku domain to communicate between the two.

Comment: thanks. I will try.
I would prefer a serve the frontend behind nginx but as I understand I cant do it in heroku.

Comment: you can use heroku nginx buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx if you want nginx with your app. I used it in Heroku.